# cakephp: jquery open map in popup div

Tags: jquery, cakephp, popup

i am working in cakephp n jquery. i have an image in cakephp and on click of that image i wish to open google map in a div popup using jquery.
I succeeded to open the map in a div on same page, but i want  it to be in a popup.
How do i do that?
 Below is my code:

//image click

```
<div class="for-route-img">
                                    <img class="fromid" id="fromId" src="/prjPool/images/route.png" />
                                </div>
```

//map is loaded in mapCanvas div:

```
<div id="markerStatus"></i></div>
<b>Current position:</b>
<div id="info"></div>
<b>Closest matching address:</b>
<div id="address"></div>
```

jquery on image click:

```
    $('#fromId').click(function(){
    var txtFrom = $("#RideofferPlace").val();

            $.ajax({ 
   url: "test",
   type: "POST",
   data:  txtFrom,
   success: function(data) {
 $("#RideofferPlace").val("");

     initialize(); // this function loads the map

},
error: function (request, status, error) {

    }
        }

    );

});
```

how do i show the div in popup using jquery?

Comment: Have a look at [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/)

Comment: well is there any other option?

Comment: Can You show code on tool like jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Have a look at. http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved it!
I used bPopup from http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/
I added the js n css in default.ctp n called:

```
$('#mapCanvas').bPopup();
```

in jquery in view.